# SQLite UPSERT error "operational error near ON"

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have a SQLite3 table that stores information about classes, with their "id" being the primary key, followed by several columns of other information. I am trying to add more class data, inserting if the class id doesn't exist and updating if it's already present. But I'm getting an error:

```
def insert_into_table(course):
  c.execute('INSERT INTO courses VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON CONFLICT'
  + ' DO UPDATE SET course_name="' + course.name + '", prereqs="' +
            course.prereqs + '", semester_offered="' + course.semester + 
            '", professor="' + course.prof + '" WHERE course_id="' + course.course_id + '";', 
            (course.course_id, course.name, course.prereqs, course.semester, course.prof,
                                                   "n/a", "n/a", "n/a", "n/a", "n/a"))
```

```
<ipython-input-49-227550f91232> in insert_into_table(course)
     38             '", professor="' + course.prof + '" WHERE course_id="' + course.course_id + '";',
     39             (course.course_id, course.name, course.prereqs, course.semester, course.prof,
---> 40                                                    "n/a", "n/a", "n/a", "n/a", "n/a"))
     41 
     42 def insert_all_into_table(courses):

OperationalError: near "ON": syntax error
```

Comment: check `sqlite3.sqlite_version` UPSERT was added with version 3.24.0

Comment: Oh, that's the problem - I'm on version 3.22.0. How could I update it (I'm in Jupyter notebook)?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know.